# Geo-blocking / geo-location. How to disable or get around it?

Tags: blocking, geolocation

There are many sites on the web these days that show a different face to you depending on where you are located around the world.

For example I'm in Australia and there are a number of US based sites I would like to see exactly as would someone living in the United States.

I've heard that most sites use your IP address to determine your country.  If so this would appear to make defeating Geo-blocking very difficult.

One of the only options I can think of is using a third party website that you visit that is based in the country you are interested in.  This site then serves a proxied view of the page.  I don't know of any sites that do this though.

Any ideas / thoughts / links?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Use an internet proxy based in the US.](http://proxy.org/)

Comment: ...or indeed in the other country of your choice.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the money getting a private proxy service is pretty cheap and easy.  Look around for US based proxy services that will filter your traffic through it's US servers and back out into the web.  That way all websites will think your traffic is originating in the US.

Answer (score 2):

You could investigate using a proxy server in the target country.

That would present a local IP address to the target website and should achieve what you want.