# Are there ways to browse a website blocked by my ISP?

Tags: internet, blocking, browsing

Is it possible to browse a website blocked by my ISP?

Comment: Please note that if your ISP blocked this website, they did so for a reason.  If/when your ISP discovers you've accessed the site against the terms of use, you'll probably be subject to sanctions and/or termination of service.

Comment: ISPs blocking websites...? What country are you in?

Comment: @Russ Warren: please note that if the ISP blocked a certain site without telling you - this is against the law. ISPs provide internet access, not access to web sites from a whitelist (this would look too much like 1984). And internet access means forwarding IP packets to you and accepting IP packets from you back. There's no such concept as web site at IP level. Of course, one could find what sites you visit by inspecting the content of IP packets, but this is generally against the law as well.

Comment: @vtest the legality of blocking is a matter of jurisdiction.  Many authoritarian states run national firewalls; and even in parts of the 'free world' organizations have occasionally gone to court to force isps to block sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a proxy to do this.

There's a few other questions that deal with proxy related surfing:

- [Geo-blocking / geo-location. How to disable or get around it?](https://superuser.com/questions/2341/)
- [Surfing the web anonymously](https://superuser.com/questions/1820/)

Answer (score 1):

[Tor](http://www.torproject.org/) will probably also let you get around it. It has its similarities with a proxy, it basically routes your traffic through a number of other connected Tor-users, and as long as their ISP will allow the access, it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an anonymous web proxy, such as http://www.kproxy.com/. There are many others as well.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate DNS service such as OpenDNS or Google Public DNS might do it.