# How to get around geographic restrictions viewing online content?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, browser-addons, blocking

Sometimes I want to watch soccer video content on British websites, but they're blocked due to geographic restrictions (I live in the US).  Is there a tool or something that I can use to get around this?

I assume the block is ip based.  I'm not interested in setting up a proxy.

Comment: Duplicate:  Several similar questions already.  http://superuser.com/questions/2341/geo-blocking-geo-location-how-to-disable-or-get-around-it for one

Comment: The answer is regarding proxies, which I'm not interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Firefox and the **Modify Headers** addon.

Tutorial:
http://www.cynicsunlimited.com/2010/03/28/using-firefox-and-modify-headers-plugin-to-view-blocked-video-streams/

Comment: +1 This is pretty much what I was looking for.  Anything similar for Chrome?

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 3):

A no-brainer solution for Chrome is [ZenMate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zenmate-for-google-chrome/fdcgdnkidjaadafnichfpabhfomcebme)

> The ZenMate extension is a free VPN -like service that lets you access sites that are blocked or censored by your government or corporation

- You can switch between 5 countries with 2 clicks
- It's not limited to just a bunch of sites
- No speed/bandwidth decrease (as far as I can tell after some month of testing)
- No constant searching for new proxy IPs

[image]

Comment: Not the only functionality of this extension. You have to click the browser button and then another button in the corner of the window that appears, but it works beautifully, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use a proxy service. http://kproxy.com is one option, but there are several others, search for "anonymous proxy" with Google.

Comment: The problem with this is that he wants to watch videos, which can sometimes be problematic through a free web proxy. Many proxies outright block flash and/or video content, and many others are too slow to watch a video without frustrating buffer times.

Comment: I'll look into that at some point for a different situation, but I was looking for solution that doesn't involve proxies. +1 for the answer though.

Comment: @DWilliams There are some that I could watch YouTube with, for example the one I linked. It also doesn't have quotas.
@Valentin If the site blocks you based on your IP, you have no other choice than to use a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Browser extensions you can use include:

- [Media Hint](https://mediahint.com/)
- [Hola Unblocker](https://hola.org/)

Alternatively if you wish to watch British Live TV from outside the UK:

- [FilmOn](http://www.filmon.com/)

Click on UK Live TV on the left, you will be presented with all the usual British TV channels.

You can then either watch in Standard Definition (SD) which is free or click on High Defintion (HD) which is a paid for service.

Then just click on fullscreen and voila you can watch all your favourite British TV programmes, exactly like as if you were in the UK.

Obviously though account for the time difference in the country you are located and plan accordingly.

Note: You can also watch FilmOn from inside the UK as well.